# Two dimensional semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

I am dealing with a two dimensional intrinsic semiconductor with a 100meV band gap. I have the conduction and valence band equations which are parabolics. Also I have been given the electron and hole effective masses ($m_n=0.01m_e$ and $m_h=m_e$). When computing the expression for n and p I make use of the density of states

$g_{2D}(E)dE=\frac{1}{2 \pi \hbar^2}\sqrt{m^*_x m^*_y} \ dE$

And I obtain a final expression for n and p which is the following:

$ n=\frac{m^*_e kT}{\pi \hbar^2} ln\left[ 1 + e^{\frac{E_F-E_C}{kT}} \right]$

$ p=\frac{m^*_h kT}{\pi \hbar^2} ln\left[ 1 + e^{\frac{E_V-E_F}{kT}} \right]$

and if I use the intrinsic condition ($n=p$) and the band gap (100meV) I can obtain $E_F-E_V$ which turns out to be 117meV (Fermi level is above the conduction band). I am aware that for 3D materials the Fermi level must be in the middle of the band, is this different for 2D materials? Or am I simply mistaken in the calculations?

Comment: I don't think that there's any requirement for 3D materials to have the Fermi level in the middle of the gap (you wrote band, but I think you meant gap). Your equations look right. What temperature are you looking at? Your effective masses are so different, that it could be that the Fermi level ends up in a weird spot. Be aware that the equations you're using can be a little dangerous for actual computation. The exponential can get very large and lead to accuracy problems. If that's the case, drop the one in the logarithm and simplify the equation.

Comment: I'll modify my statement slightly. The Fermi level will only be in the middle of the bandgap for 3D materials if 1) the hole and electron effective masses are the same or 2) the temperature is zero. For a reference, see R. F. Pierret's "Semiconductor Device Fundamentals" section 2.5.6. 2D materials will be similar.

Comment: I finally solved the question, the main "issue" was that the great difference between $m^*_e$ and $m^*_h$. As you pointed out the Fermi level is in the middle of the gap for certain conditions (at room temperature and $m^*_e$ $\approx$ $m^*_h$ is quite near though). @Inmaurer